# How to better import/export XML to Database, having XML with schema?

Tags: xml, database, schema

Do you know best practicies ?

Comment: Different databases could have different solutions. What's database you are working with?

Comment: Access. but the main idea is how to map tree-like model to relational database model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my thesis (Java 1.4) I resolved this problem in this way:

1. DOM parsing  (but *SAX* way is better) for reading the XML file and insert the values in a Collection of Object (1 Collection for 1 type of node);
2. cycle of this array: in the cycle , at the *k* step, I build a **StringBuffer** of the SQL **insert** adding the k-Object (as a String: using the **toString()** implemented correctly) in the *k*-place;
3. execute **insert** of this StringBuffer with another or the same cycle;

This system is a draft: really you can optimize decreasing the number of step, etc.

The XML schema is useless at run-time with this system, but you cuold use it for project the database.

Is'nt a very optimized and elegant system, but it works :)